# How to install and use Windows Assessment and Deployment SDK on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wadk

I've recently installed the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (WADK) on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've used the installer provided by Microsoft here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39982

The installer says on the page that it's intended for Windows 8.1, however I can't find a version specific to Server 2008 R2. I've run the installer and it appears to install just fine. However, when I try to use the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` cmdlet in the DISM PowerShell module installed with the ADK, it fails (using commands verified to work on Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 machines). I specifically installed the ADK solely for this Powershell module. Does anybody know how I can get the DISM PowerShell module working on Server 2008 R2, or alternatively, find another way to install it that will work correctly ?

I need this module to be able to automate installation of some optional features in live running instances of Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I my installation scripts, I check for the OS version and use `dism.exe`directly if I'm still on 2008 R2, or use `Add-WindowsFeature` but that uses completely different feature names.

Comment: Something created for the desktop OS will usually work with it's server OS counterpart.  In this case, the counterpart for 8.1 was 2012 r2.  You're essentially asking to install a program intended for 8.1 on windows vista.  It's not going to work.

Comment: @Colyn1337 The documentation I've seen indicated that this specific package would work with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008